# Dropwizard task won't accept more than 1 parameter

Tags: java, uri, task, dropwizard

So, I need to create a specific task that will be called with POST request when needed, so I am using drop wizard's Task interface, I have created a class that extends a task, registered it in /tasks/ interface and I am calling it with this call:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/tasks/StoreMigration?maxRows=4&date=2014-02-2T15:23:00Z
```

whichever parameter I put first, that one shows up in my Task, second one disappears. Any idea how to handle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, the problem was in & character which would put process in background, solution is quite trivial:

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8081/tasks/StoreMigration?date=2014-02-2T15:23:00Z&maxRows=4'
```